# Mismatched types lifetime requirement error

Tags: rust

I have an error message that is confusing me. Here is the message in its entirety:

```
mismatched types
expected trait `for<'r> <for<'r> fn(std::option::Option<&'r mut [Value]>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = TestRepo<goods::data::Repository>> {test_repo_setup} as FnOnce<(std::option::Option<&'r mut [Value]>,)>>`
   found trait `for<'r> <for<'r> fn(std::option::Option<&'r mut [Value]>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = TestRepo<goods::data::Repository>> {test_repo_setup} as FnOnce<(std::option::Option<&'r mut [Value]>,)>>`rustcE0308
common.rs(76, 37): the lifetime requirement is introduced here
```

The `common.rs(76, 37)` refers to a line in the definition of this complex function:

```
pub async fn test_framework<FI, FR, FutR, R, FE, FutE, V> (
    init_func: FI,
    repo_func: FR,
    repo_data: Option<&mut [Value]>,
    arg: Argument,
    exec_func: FE, 
    exp: Expected<V>,
) where 
    FI: Fn(),
--> FR: Fn(Option<&mut [Value]>) -> FutR,
    FutR: std::future::Future<Output = R>,
    FE: Fn(R, Argument) -> FutE,
    FutE: std::future::Future<Output = ServiceResponse>,
    V: serde::de::DeserializeOwned + PartialEq + std::fmt::Debug,
{
```

The reference to `test_repo_setup` is the function passed as the `repo_func` parameter of type `FR`:

```
pub async fn test_repo_setup(data: Option<&mut [Value]>) -> TestRepo<Repository> {
   ...
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure where to start with this error message. The error message shows that the two traits are identical. I can't figure out where, if anywhere the elided lifetime trap would be happening.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Please post a reproducible code and the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know what the code logic might be. But if my guess is right it might be similar to this code, which won't compile:

```
fn create_future<FR> (
    func: FR,
    data: Option<&u32>,
) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = u32>
where
    FR: Fn(Option<&u32>) -> u32
{
    async move {
        func(data)
    }
}
```

Because the compiler cannot be sure that the `&u32` captured by the created future will live as long as the future. Lifetime annotations would be needed to tell the compiler that how long `func` and the future will live, with respect to the `&u32`.

```
fn create_future<'a, FR> (
    func: FR,
    data: Option<&'a u32>,
) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = u32> + 'a
where
    FR: Fn(Option<&'a u32>) -> u32 + 'a
{
    async move {
        func(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the solution. I needed to add a specified lifetime both to the function and to the FR argument (thought I did not need to add it to the return value of FR, as you did here).